# SQL Selecting column names as values

Tags: sql, view

I have a table of data with column names:

```
period, Truck, Car, Boat
```

Where the Columns contain numeric values, and the period column is an identity column having 1 to 48, so there are 48 rows.

I would like to massage this table into a format where I have a Name column and a value column as well as the period column eg.

```
period, NameOfVehicle, Value
```

I want to create a view of the orignal table to do this? How can I select the column names and place them and the correct value from that column into the NameOfVehicle and Value columns?

Comment: You're going to need to be more specific about the data you have - how exactly should the contents of NameOfVehicle be determined, etc

Comment: The contents of NameAndVehicle are Truck, Car, and Boat.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have fixed columns you can always do this:

```
SELECT period, 'Truck' AS NameOfVehicle, Truck AS Value FROM vehicle
UNION ALL
SELECT period, 'Car', Car FROM vehicle
UNION ALL
SELECT period, 'Boat', Boat FROM vehicle
```

If the columns are dynamic or unknown then it's a bit harder and will rely on vendor-specific functionality to query the schema and a dynamic SQL statement.

Answer (score 4):

While cletus's query is correct, it's worth pointing out that you can use the keyword UNPIVOT in SQL Server 2005 and later to do almost the same thing:

```
  select
    period, nameOfVehicle, value
  from T unpivot (
    value for nameOfVehicle in ([Car],[Truck],[Boat])
  ) as U;
```

The difference between UNPIVOT and cletus's solution is that UNPIVOT will not include rows for which [value] IS NULL. If you need the NULLs, you'll have to be somewhat sneaky and use a value that can never occur in the table (here I use an empty string):

```
with X(period,Car,Truck,Boat) as (
  select period,coalesce(Car,''),coalesce(Truck,''),coalesce(Boat,'')
  from T
)
  select
    period, nameOfVehicle, case when value = '' then null else value end as value
  from X unpivot (
    value for nameOfVehicle in ([Car],[Truck],[Boat])
  ) as U;
```

Depending on the columns you'll keep after unpivoting, this may be another option (this solution will retain the NULL values):

```
select
  period,
  nameOfVehicle,
  max(case nameOfVehicle 
      when 'Truck' then Truck
      when 'Car' then Car
      when 'Boat' then Boat end) as value
  from T cross join (
  values ('Truck'),('Car'),('Boat')
) as Columns(nameOfVehicle)
group by period, nameOfVehicle;
```