# SQL Server change column name for description

Tags: sql-server

I have a table `dbo.EX_DD12` that shows data, but the table columns have a code assigned (`DD12001, DD12002, DD12003....DD12055`).

This query:

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo.EX_DD12]
```

returns results something like this:

```
Id | DD12001    | DD12002    | DD12003  
---+------------+------------+--------
 1 | 12/12/2005 | 10:00 a.m. | x  
 2 | 13/12/2005 | 10:00 a.m. | y  
 3 | 14/12/2005 | 09:00 a.m. | x
```

Using this query I can get the description:

```
SELECT 
    T0.name, T1.Description
INTO 
    #TABLE00
FROM 
    sys.columns T0
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.EXDT T1 ON T0.name = Code
WHERE 
    object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.EX_DD12') 
    AND T0.name LIKE 'DD12%'
```

The results look something like this:

```
Code    | Description  
--------+-------------
DD12001 | Date  
DD12002 | Time  
DD12003 | Priority
```

What can I do so that in a query the results looks like this?

```
Id | Date       | Time       | Priority
---+------------+------------+---------
 1 | 12/12/2005 | 10:00 a.m. | x  
 2 | 13/12/2005 | 10:00 a.m. | y  
 3 | 14/12/2005 | 09:00 a.m. | x
```

Comment: Just a note: Usually databases that are obfuscated are like that for a reason and have a web service / other integration point that you should use instead of database queries....

Comment: refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252580/sql-selecting-column-names-as-values

Comment: Just add the alias

Comment: I dont think he wants to add alias, he wants to FETCH the description from other table name as COLUMN_NAME

Comment: @uSeruSher He don't want to add alias but he has to do it

Comment: i'm looking for another way insted of alias, because there are about 100 columns, in the example I used 3

Comment: which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server:

Building a query dynamically and executing with `sp_executesql`:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);
declare @tbl sysname = 'dbo.EX_DD12'

select @sql = 'select' + char(10)
  + stuff((
    select char(10)+'  , '+quotename(c.name) + case 
        when c.name != d.description 
          then ' as ' +quotename(coalesce(d.[Description],c.name)) 
        else '' 
        end
      from sys.columns c 
        left join dbo.EXDT d
          on c.name = d.[Code]
      where c.object_id = object_id(@tbl)
      order by c.column_id 
    for xml path (''), type).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
    ,1,5,'    ')+ char(10)
  +'from '+quotename(schema_name(t.schema_id))+'.'+quotename(object_name(object_id(@tbl)))
  from sys.tables t where t.object_id = object_id(@tbl)

select @sql as CodeGenerated;
--exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/GGEL20070

returns:

```
+-----------------------------+
|        CodeGenerated        |
+-----------------------------+
| select                      |
|     [id]                    |
|   , [DD12001] as [Date]     |
|   , [DD12002] as [Time]     |
|   , [DD12003] as [Priority] |
| from [dbo].[EX_DD12]        |
+-----------------------------+
```

dynamic sql reference:

- [The curse and blessings of dynamic SQL - Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)
- [**`sp_executesql`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql)